# Zonal Statistics not running in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis-3, zonal-statistics

I am working on Nighttime light data from NOAA. The study area is India at state level. After masking the raster, when I am trying to run the zonal statistics with raster and vector polygon layer (screen shot attached), the small window of zonal statistics just flickers and does not run. Though the log section says that '*Algorithm zonal statistics finished*' but it does not run. It does not add any new columns in the vector polygon attribute table. The attribute table is as it is as it was before. I have been trying to run this for last two days, but it does not help.

What could be the possible reason for it? I am currently using QGIS version 3.12.[image]

Comment: Again tried on stable version. The small popped up window only flickers once on pressing the 'run' button but it does not execute and create any new columns in the polygon vector. Though the log section shows this msg.......

Comment: Algorithm 'Zonal statistics' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : 'NTL_', 'INPUT_RASTER' : 'C:/Users/visha/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_a8cd37cc2d5d452d97b84162057ac0e1/f18b7a6d36c64d1796c27f15caf68884/OUTPUT.tif', 'INPUT_VECTOR' : '/vsizip/C:/Users/visha/Downloads/gadm36_IND_shp.zip/gadm36_IND_0.shp', 'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'STATS' : [0,1,2] }

Execution completed in 0.05 seconds
Results:
{'INPUT_VECTOR': <QgsMapLayer: 'gadm36_IND_0' (ogr)>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Zonal statistics' finished

Comment: Please help. Stuck with this for long.

Comment: Zonal statistics should create a temporary layer with information. This layer is where the attribute table is viewed. I myself have encountered such a problem, but I can't solve it yet.